# How can I send a file to a user in the Teams channel?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a file (calendar ics file) in the Teams channel. I am using the below code which works fine in webchat channel:

```js
const reminder = fs.readFileSync(`temp/reminder.ics`);
const base64reminder = Buffer.from(reminder).toString('base64');

await dc.context.sendActivity({'text':'Click here to set up a reminder on your calendar', 'attachments': [{
    name: 'Leader X Activities',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    contentUrl: `data:text/calendar;base64,${ base64reminder }`}]
});
```

I have used both text/plain and text/calendar, the type there didn't make a difference. But teams is throwing an **Unknown attachment type** error. Here is what I captured in App Insights.

```js
{"error":"Unknown attachment type","callStack":"Error: Unknown attachment type\n at new RestError (D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\@azure\\ms-rest-js\\dist\\msRest.node.js:1399:28)\n at D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\@azure\\ms-rest-js\\dist\\msRest.node.js:2495:37\n at <anonymous>\n at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)","botName":"itInnovationBot"}
```

I've tried to review the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=typescript), but I can't make any sense out of what it's doing with the consent and then send files. It's also using different syntax than I am, probably because it is extending TeamsActivityHandler. I'm doing this inside a waterfall dialog extending ComponentDialog, so I'm not even sure I could utilize that class if I wanted to.

It seems like I need to ask for some sort of consent to send a file, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this. What do I ened to do in order to get this ics file attached in Teams?

I am somewhat interested in doing this directly via Graph API, but I believe we have some internal corporate roadblocks to this, which is why I am trying an initial implementation with ics file attachment. And besides, that would solve only ics files and I know we will need to have the bot send other file types in the future.

**EDIT:** I've tried a few other things where I've perhaps made a bit of progress, but it's still not working. The below gets rid of the unknown attachment error but it is replaced with empty content error:

```js
await dc.context.sendActivity({'text':'Click here to set up a reminder on your calendar', 'attachments': [{
    name: 'Leader X Activities',
    contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info',
    contentUrl: `data:text/calendar;base64,${ base64reminder }`}]
});
```

Adding the content object I just get a "ServiceError/Unknown" error, which isn't very helpful troubleshooting further. I've tried all kinds of different information in the content object all with the same result.

```js
await dc.context.sendActivity({'text':'Click here to set up a reminder on your calendar', 'attachments': [{
    name: 'Leader X Activities',
    contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info',
    contentUrl: `data:text/calendar;base64,${ base64reminder }`,
    content: {
        uniqueId: '12345whatever'
        contentType: 'text/plain'
    }}]
});
```

**EDIT 2:** One further update, I've tried setting a consent card, with the assumption that I can then look for an "invoke" activity, but the consent buttons don't seem to actually generate any activity. Here's the code:

```js
await dc.context.sendActivity({'attachments': [{
    content: {
        description: 'Here is the file I want to send you',
        fileSizeInBytes: fileSizeInBytes,
        accetpContext: fileContext,
        declineContext: fileContext
    },
    contentType: 'application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.consent',
    name: 'reminder.ics'}]
})
```

**EDIT 3:** I didn't get any message or indication of activity from desktop app, but when I tried to click on the consent buttons from mobile app it was giving me a "BOTNAME does not support files" error message, even though in the teams app manifest I do have it set to support files. So it seems I'm not getting an activity because that button press is getting blocked. Not sure if this is because I am not using TeamsActivityHandler (and if that is required, then I will need to know how to incorporate that into a waterfall dialog that is using ComponentDialog).

Comment: Just curious, did you test send an actual url instead of Base64?

Comment: Also I am not familior with javascript API, but their example says you should create a reply activity and send the activilty back.
        var replyActivity = this.createReply(context.activity);
        replyActivity.attachments = [ attachment ]; await context.sendActivity(replyActivity);

Comment: That syntax is unfamiliar to me. I think it's either an updated SDK or possibly specific to the TeamsActivityHandler. My class is an extension of ComponentDialog and I'd like to continue with it as is if that's possible. My file is in the local dev directory but I can certainly try not converting to base64 (it didn't work for webchat channel, though).

Comment: Sending a file to channel, either you can try from the bot or Graph API. This is the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload/bots/teamsFileUploadBot.js) for bot.

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT I've looked at that sample but can't get it to work. The code in the question is what I have tried to adapt that sample to my requirements. I need guidance on things like do I need to have this accept dialog, is TeamsActivityHandler required, and why is Teams saying my bot can't accept files even though it is set to do so in the app manifest?

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT also I want to specify that this file is being generated by the bot. I don't really want to upload it anywhere. I'm currently writing it to a temporary file in local storage (and removing afterwards) but if there were a way to handle this without even writing the file to storage I could do that.

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT Any further input or can you help escalate this? I'm having trouble finding any definitive documentation on attaching files in teams beyond the sample you linked to, which I was not able to adapt to my use case.

Comment: For now, the ability to receive file attachments and send files to the user is restricted to 1:1 chats with the bot.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT This bot is deployed in personal scope only, not group chat, just 1:1. But either I ask for permission and nothing happens after they allow, or I try to attach directly and Teams says unknown file type.

Comment: @billoverton, From where you are attaching the file, i mean is it from locallfolder from where your solution is places or from any meeting url ?

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT Local folder in solution (something like wwwdev/temp/reminder.ics)

Comment: @VaraPrasad-MSFT any additional thoughts or things to try here for my use case?

Comment: @billoverton , we are investigating your issue internally and will get back to you asap.